# Passing from server select values and labels

Tags: yadcf

Is it possible to pass from server select values and labels.

It would be nice to be able pass to pass id's and string representations to `select2`.

For example, I want to pass `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], ["name1", "name2" ..., "name5"]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like in the client side setup of yadcf you can send from server an *array of objects* with value / label

See in [Server side source example](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/server_side_source.html) inspect the dev tools -> Network - > entrys_table_server_side_source, look at the yadcf_data_0

```
yadcf_data_0: [{value: "Trident", label: "Trident Eng'"}, 
               {value: "Tasman", label: "Tasman Eng'"},…]
```

Comment: Thanks :). I saw server side example, but somehow I missed that part.

Comment: Its because I updated the showcase with this sample after I saw you question